# Why does the query that creates the view run faster than Select 1000 from same view

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have built a query that I have turned into a view, the query within the view runs in about 9 minutes with a row count of 1.6 million.  When I query Select Top 1000 from that view it runs continuously without supplying any results. Why would something like this happen?

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[v_BP_OP] 
AS  

--pulls ORCA BPs

with OBP as (
SELECT DISTINCT s.EPI 
            ,e.CONTACT_DATE 
            ,s.EventDtTm 
            ,s.SBP 
            ,d.dbp

FROM uwEpicClarity.dbo.PAT_ENC e 
with(nolock)
INNER JOIN [uwQAQI_DS].[dbo].[v_BP_Systolic]s
with(nolock)on e.EPI = s.EPI and CONVERT(date,e.CONTACT_DATE) =      CONVERT(date,s.EventDtTm)
INNER JOIN [uwQAQI_DS].[dbo].[v_BP_Diastolic]d
with(nolock)on s.EID = d.EID and s.EventDtTm = d.EventDtTm 

WHERE e.CONTACT_DATE >= '2014-01-01'
and e.ENC_TYPE_C in (50,101)
and e.APPT_STATUS_C_DESCR in ('Completed','Arrived')
and s.Src = 'ORCA_CE'
and d.Src = 'ORCA_CE'
        )

--combines ORCA and Epic BPS            
SELECT DISTINCT EPI 
,CONTACT_DATE 
,EventDtTm 
,CAST(SBP as varchar) + '/' + CAST(DBP as varchar) as Meas_Value
,'ORCA' as SrcSys
FROM obp

UNION

SELECT DISTINCT e.EPI 
        ,e.CONTACT_DATE
        ,fm.[RECORDED_TIME]
        ,CAST(MEAS_VALUE as varchar)as MEAS_VALUE
        ,'Epic' as SrcSys


  FROM [uwEpicClarity].[dbo].[IP_FLWSHT_MEAS] fm with (NoLock)
  INNER JOIN uwEpicClarity.dbo.[IP_FLWSHT_REC] fr with (NoLock) on fm.FSD_ID   = fr.FSD_ID
  INNER JOIN uwEpicClarity.dbo.PAT_ENC e with (NoLock) on   fr.INPATIENT_DATA_ID = e.INPATIENT_DATA_ID
  WHERE e.CONTACT_DATE >= '2014-01-01' 
  and FLO_MEAS_ID in ('5','116')
  and e.ENC_TYPE_C in (50,101)
and e.APPT_STATUS_C_DESCR in ('Completed','Arrived')





GO
```

Comment: Work with a DBA (or ask at http://dba.stackexchange.com) to look at each of the execution plans.  There's not nearly enough information to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: would adding the query that built the view be helpful?

Comment: You probably have an ORDER BY in the query. That would force the entire result set to be materialized before the top can be taken.

Comment: @AndrewMo Yes it would be helpful

Comment: Rather post the two execution plans.

Comment: I guess the unions like order by force all results to be returned, since union needs set comparison of elements from each sub query. Try "UNION ALL".

Comment: Also, `SELECT DISTINCT` may require sorting to filter out duplicate result rows.  Still, all of this speaks to why the view's query is slow, but not to why selecting the top 1000 results from it is [much] slower than selecting everything.

Comment: Note that in this case the `UNION` cannot ever give you a different result than `UNION ALL` would do, because the rows in the left rowset always have a different `SrcSys` than those in the right rowset, and neither the left nor the right rowset contains any duplicate rows.  Don't mess around with whether the query optimizer would figure that out -- just use `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Note also that temporary table OBP is already assured of having no duplicate rows; it is therefore not useful to `SELECT DISTINCT` from it.  Again, don't rely on the query optimizer to figure that out -- just use an ordinary `SELECT`.

Comment: And why anyway are you using temp table `OBP` at all?  You don't need it; just put its defining query directly on the left side of your `UNION [ALL]`, tweaked as appropriate.

Comment: Also, it would be worthwhile evaluating whether you actually need `SELECT DISTINCT` in the other places you use it.  That cannot be determined from the query alone, but if, for example, you can rely on the combinations of (EPI, EventDtTm) pairs to be distinct for every row anyway, then just drop all the `DISTINCT`s.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions.  I will make some adjustments and let you know what I find ASAP.

Comment: Applied the changes John Bollinger suggested but the Select Top 1000 is still running slower than the actual query. I ran the execution plans and it states something about creating a non clustered index. Guess I will look into that and see if that would help.  Thanks again